# adRequest.addTestDevice() argument requirements are confusing me

Tags: java, android, admob

When I do a

```
adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

logcat seems to report that I am requesting an ad but then says

```
09-21 11:48:13.720: W/Ads(712): Invalid unknown request error: Cannot determine request type.
```

Is your ad unit id correct?
Yet the id I am using is correctly pasted from the AdMod API code request/response screen.  What am I doing wrong?

I am more puzzled when I try to use a real device (HTC Inspire running Android 2.2.1).  Logcat is silent, yet I get no test ad.  Can someone tell me exactly what to put in place of "xxxxxxxx" in the following:

```
adRequest.addTestDevice("xxxxxxxx");
```

I have tried the text string "TEST_DEVICE_ID", the serial number of my device, and stuff even dumber.  No joy. Do I need to hash the serial number or something?  I am using JDK 1.7.

Answer (score 5):

Check your ad unit id. Is it the ad unit ID you got from AdMob?  Do you have any whitespace in your ad unit?  You're getting that error because AdMob doesn't recognize that ID.

As for setting test devices, you set test mode for the emulator via:

```
adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
```

For setting test mode on device, make an AdRequest on device, and check LogCat.  The SDK will says something like:

```
To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice("0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF");
```

This number is a hash of your device ID, and it's easiest to get from LogCat.

Comment: Thanks guys.  Very helpful suggestions.  My biggest error was to incorrectly use an API Code that I got from AdMob instead of the Publishers ID.  Fixing that gives me test ads on the emulator and real ads on the HTC Inspire.  However, I am still not getting LogCat output with the HTC Inspire so I can't determine the string for getting test ads on it.  Need to research this LogCat problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I don't know if you addressed the issues of the difference of being in emulator vs on a real device in your code. You need to distinguish between your app being run on an emulator or real device, this can be done with the following

```
    boolean inEmulator = "generic".equals(Build.BRAND.toLowerCase());
```

This will come back true if you are in an emulator and false if you are not. Next you need to build a way to handle the ads depending on the value of inEmulaotor

```
    if (inEmulator) 
    {
        adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
    } 
    else 
    {
        adRequest.addTestDevice("11111111101111111110111111111011");
    }
```

Here we either have to add an emulator test device, or you 32char Device ID of a real Device. (this ID is alphanumeric) This Id for a real device can be found by running admob on the real device out of test mode, and will appear in logcat.

Finally you need to set testing = true and start loading the ads.

```
    adRequest.setTesting(true);
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

So all in all, a working set of this code might look like :

```
    boolean isTestingAds = true; //this is a switch, to make it easy on changing modes

    boolean inEmulator = "generic".equals(Build.BRAND.toLowerCase());
    AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, MY_AD_UNIT_ID);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();

    if (isTestingAds) 
    {
        if (inEmulator) 
        {
            adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
        } 
        else 
        {
            adRequest.addTestDevice("11111111101111111110111111111011");
        }
        adRequest.setTesting(true);
    }

    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Don't forget to add the adview to your content view, as well as update manifest file. MY_AD_UNIT_ID is the code you get from admob for this particular app.

So finally to find your ID, set

```
    isTestingAds = false;
```

and then the # you need to set your device to test will appear in LogCat.

If you are not getting and logcat data from your real device, then that is another issue altogether.